# Error When Navigating to Parent's Sibling Using Angular Router

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-router

I have the following component structure:

```
AppComponent
--NetworkComponent
----HeaderComponent
----HomeComponent
------SideProfileComponent
------FeedComponent
----ProfileComponent
```

I am trying to navigate from `SideProfileComponent` to `ProfileComponent`
using `routerLink` as follows:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user', user.username]">
   <div class="name">{{ user.firstname }} {{user.lastname}}</div>
   <div>@{{ user.username }}</div>
</a>
```

When I do so, the page does indeed navigate to the desired component, but in the console, the following error is thrown

[image]
When I am in the `HomeComponent` (with `SideProfileComponent` loaded in it) and use the link on the `HeaderComponent` to navigate to `ProfileComponent` then the error doesn't appear!

What is the problem that's causing the error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null** to appear?

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: NetworkComponent,
        canActivate: [NetworkAuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: NetworkHomeComponent,
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'user/:username',
                component: NetworkProfileComponent
            },

        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: ''
    },
]

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]   
})

export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

Comment: where is the route for side profile component ?

Comment: @RahulSingh I include it inside of the `NetworkHomeComponent` using `<app-side-profile></app-side-profile>`

Comment: how are you routing can you post that ?

Comment: @RahulSingh Just added it